# React Folder Structure Questions

Tags: reactjs, mongodb

I'm currently trying to make a turn-based game for a class project using gameboard.io. My biggest issue is I don't know how to set up my folder structure with react and MongoDB as its a new technology I've been using.

I've tried a couple of different things but every time I try to use mongoDB I get loads of errors and files missing/not connecting and I'm sure my folder structure is broken.

Can anyone help me with an outline for a folder structure using those technologies? I know this isn't a typical question but I've been struggling with this. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I think the googleable buzz word you're looking for is *scaffolding* an application. [Yeoman](https://yeoman.io/) is a tool I've heard of for that. I'm sure there's plenty of generators there that are decent enough. I don't know enough to recommend any specific one.

Answer (score 0):

Normally mongoDB runs on the back-end. Your front-end application would interact with mongo through an api. If you want to use a node.js powered back-end server application, express is a popular choice, but there are many others ( koa, hapi, Meteor, ...to name a few).

Then install mongoDB on (not the npm package but the server application, the npm package is the mongoDB driver that you use in your application to connect to the database, you will find instructions on mongoDB's website), I would also recommend installing mongoose, it's an object data modeling library.

If I where you, start with installing express, and work on communicating with express from your react app. Then install mongo/mongoose, and give it a try.